# how to use gmapping based on laser_scan_matcher?

Tags: slam, navigation, lidar, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I now only have .pcap file collected by my velodyne. I want to test gampping without a moving robot.

Here are the steps I did:

```
roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16_points.launch pcap:=/home/soowon/Documents/County_Fair.pcap
```

...

```
rosrun pointcloud_to_laserscan pointcloud_to_laserscan_node cloud_in:=/velodyne_points
```

At this moment, I can see the laserscan in RVIZ with frame of "velodyne", then I run this to get fake /tf:

```
rosrun laser_scan_matcher laser_scan_matcher_node scan:=/scan
```

..

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=/scan
```

No error occurs, but I cannot see anything new in RVIZ, I added the topic map, but it says "no map received". I tried different frames in RVIZ, like: velodyne, map, world. It does not work.

Can anybody tell me what is the reason? Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254406/how-to-use-gmapping-based-on-laser_scan_matcher?/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-02-11**:
How to you expect gmapping to interpret the lack of odometry?

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-11**:
@joq, http://answers.ros.org/question/254371/can-i-test-gmapping-without-a-moving-robot/ in this quesiton, somebody says laser_scan_matcher can provide odometry.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-02-15**:
All right. Good luck with that.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-03-28**:
Any progress to report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@joq I gave up and use hector slam instead...

---

Originally posted by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) with karma: 141 on 2017-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-04-05**:
Sounds like a reasonable answer to me.

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-05-04**:
I recently again began to use gmapping, but now I have odometry and not need laser_scan_matcher anymore. Here is my progress up to now: [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/261133/map-generated-is-not-continuous/)